# HR Block Software reduces my tax return by $53 after entering crypto gain of $13

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, cryptocurrency

Some time this year I purchased 0.1 ETH for $260 and a few days later sold it for $273 which is a gain of $13. However, when I enter these amounts into form 1099 in HR Block software that reduces my tax refund by $53.

How is this even possible or is it just an error in their software?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without looking at your whole tax return. If I were to guess, I'd suggest to check that it does in fact calculate the gain correctly, $53 looks suspiciously like the tax you'd pay if all the $273 were gain.

Comment: Did you receive a 1099 for this transaction?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica Yes, it was labeled "2021 Crypto IRS Form 1099" and inside the document there is a note stating "These transactions should be reported on Form 8949 Part I with box C checked.".

Comment: Is it a 1099-B? Does it include both the “$273” and “$260” numbers on it?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica Unfortunately, the form was only labeled as "2021 Crypto IRS Form 1099" on WeBull website and there is no form number on the document itself...

Comment: Does it include both numbers on it?

Comment: Yes, both numbers are included as well as Gain/Loss number...

Comment: @DeanKuga and Gain/Loss number is $13? If yes, I would experiment by putting purchase of $1 and sale at $14 to see what happens.

Comment: Yes, Gain/Loss is $13. I'll try that and let you know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out crypto proceeds need to be reported on form 8949 Part I with box C checked...

In H&R Block software after searching for 8949 I selected option "Sale of Collectibles and Other Investment Property" and after entering proceeds values correct amount was witheld...

[image: HRBLock]